# How to make photos share by e-mail with an animation?

Tags: ios, uikit

In iPhone's Photos built-in app, when we open a picture, click share, then "e-mail", the photo "flies away", a new VC appears from below, then the attachment "attaches". I wonder how (if) this can be achieved from a `UICollectionViewController` cell.

My plan is to create a custom segue with an `UICollectionViewCell` as sender and an arbitrary `UIViewController` as destination.

I mixed some of UIView's `transitionWithView` and `animateWithDuration`, without success.